# How to detect bad_lines when reading a pandas dataframe by chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I want pandas to drop those lines with more columns than headers while I am reading the file by chunks.

Let us imagine this simple dataset:

```
col_A,col_B,col_C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9,10
11,12
```

If I perform the following action, the behavior is exactly as I want:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./datasets/test_bad_lines.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
df.shape  # (3, 3)
```

But If I read it by chunks:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('./datasets/test_bad_lines.csv', chunksize=2):
    print(chunk)
```

Pandas does not drop any line, instead of that it truncates the problematic row to fit with the headers size, which is a behavior that I do not want.

```
   col_A  col_B  col_C
0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6

   col_A  col_B  col_C
2      7      8    9.0
3     11     12    NaN
```

So, taking into account that read the dataset by chunks is a must due to its big size, does anybody know how to achieve the described behavior (the removal of the problematic lines)?

Comment: did you try to add error_bad_lines = False to your for loop? I have seen it used in the past, but not sure if this will fix your problem

Comment: Add that parameter into the loop doesn't change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df =  pd.read_csv('test_bad_lines.csv.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
print(np.array_split(df, 2))
```

Comment: *"[...] read the dataset by chunks is a must due to its big size"* That's not quite what the OP wants.